# how to take a value from one div to another onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a search function for this, so when the user clicks on the button to apply a search, I want the value to remain in the field onclick.

html

```
 <div class="search">
       <input type="text" id="searchtext" placeholder="Search">
       <a href="#" class="search-text button">GO</a>
 </div>

 $('.search button').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
     document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML;
 });
```

or jquery

```
 $('#searchtext').val() = $('#searchtext').val();
```

tried this too:

```
$("#searchtext").html() = ("#searchtext").html();
```

When the user clicks on the search button, if they search for "text", then "text will stay in the field on page load removing any placeholder there.

Comment: Try removing `#` from `document.getElementById("#searchtext")` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Don't mix jquery and vanilla js if you don't know what is what. Try to learn first.

Comment: There is no point in assigning an element's innerHTML to its own innerHTML.

Comment: then how would you do it then?

Comment: i took out the #, didnt work

Comment: @Keith _"i took out the #, didnt work"_ Can you include `html` at Question ?, create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to demonstrate ?

Comment: use `$("#searchtext").html($("#searchtext").html())` instead ..  You can't use =

Comment: if you want to display previous values , do it with server side language or use local storage

Comment: Add html code! so answer will be more easy

Comment: @Keith `js` at Question uses `$('.search button')` selector though there does not appear to be `button` element at `html` ? _"When the user clicks on the search button, if they search for "text", then "text will stay in the field on page load removing any placeholder there."_ What do you mean by "if they search for "text"" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some help on this one, but bascially you store the query and then split it up so that it gets put into your div of where the value needs to be.

```
var params = {}, href = window.location.search, hashes = (href.length > 0) ?   href.replace('&amp;', '&').slice(1).split('&') : [];
for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
var hash = hashes[i].split('=');
params[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
$('.search input').val(params['search']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting for a moment that you seem to be filling the `innerHTML` of one DIV with it's own `innerHTML` value (which will achieve nothing), you are mixing jQuery and vanilla JS. You should do one or the other:

#### jQuery:

```
$('.search button').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var searchElement = $("#searchtext");
  searchElement.html(searchElement.html());
});
```

#### Vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.search button')[0].addEventListener('click',  function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var searchElement = document.getElementById('searchtext');
  searchElement.innerHTML = 'test';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using **jQuery**

```
    $('.search button').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var val = $("#searchElement").html();
      $("#searchElement").html(val );
    });
```

Comment: try assigning value to another var and then use that var to set html()

Comment: This gets and stores the value, but once the page reloads it doesn't keep the value there:     var p = $('#searchtext').val();
    $('#searchtext').html(p);

Comment: have you tried using hidden input field? assign value of p to hidden input and at page load assign hidden input value to your element again